# How can I get those last XML items using xPath or anything else?

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, xmldocument

I've used the child elements of the first node `PovprecnaPlaca` before I noticed I need the child elements of the last one.

Picture of XML for reference:

[image: Picture of XML for reference]

Appreciate all the helpful answers!

XML looks like this:

```xml
<PovprecnaPlaca>
   <Datum>2017-07-01T00:00:00</Datum>
   <BrutoPlacaZadnje3Mesece>1603,00</BrutoPlacaZadnje3Mesece>
   <NetoPlacaZadnje3Mesece>1045,12</NetoPlacaZadnje3Mesece>
   <BrutoPlaca>1593,10</BrutoPlaca>
   <NetoPlaca>1039,55</NetoPlaca>
 </PovprecnaPlaca>
 <PovprecnaPlaca>
   <Datum>2017-08-01T00:00:00</Datum>
   <BrutoPlacaZadnje3Mesece>1602,98</BrutoPlacaZadnje3Mesece>
   <NetoPlacaZadnje3Mesece>1045,45</NetoPlacaZadnje3Mesece>
   <BrutoPlaca>1613,62</BrutoPlaca>
   <NetoPlaca>1051,73</NetoPlaca>
  </PovprecnaPlaca>
 </Place>
</PovprecnePlace>
```

Comment: The Xpath you're using is incorrect. Also need to cast the result. Do you want only the last date of the file or the last for each `Place` node? Please add your code to the question, not an image.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, will add my code. I want the last of each    place  node, i was just trying to experiment with getting the last date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `Datum` node from the last `PovprecnaPlaca` of each `Place`.

```
var nodes = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//PovprecnaPlaca[last()]/Datum");
```

Get the text inside each node.

```
List<string> results = nodes.Select(d => d.Value).ToList();
```

Two reasons why your attemp didn't work: 1) It starts from root node "/" of the document and there's no `PovprecnaPlaca` node at this level. 2) By calling `text()` it's getting `XText` which raises an exception in Linq as it expects nodes as a result when calling `XPathSelectElements()`.

Comment: I changed PovprecnaPlaca with Placa when debugging, so i had it right at first. But I couldn't get it to work, probably because i don't know how to use '/' and '//'. Thank you for your answer:)